# Wordpress dropdown menu (bootstrap)

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4

I created menu in my Wordpress, one of the menu items has a sub-menu. So, how should I modification this code to get dropdown navs like in Bootstrap Navs?

```
<?php 
       wp_nav_menu(array(
       'theme-location'=>'header_menu',
       'menu_class' => 'nav',
       'my_menu_li_class' => 'nav-item',
        'my_menu_a_class' => 'nav-link js-scroll-trigger'
                        
    )); 
?>
```

Bootstrap example:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

1. I added this code to my catalog with the [theme](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/blob/master/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php)
2. In function.php I added this code:

```
function register_navwalker() {
   require_once get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_navwalker' );
```

3. Then in the menu code I added arguments:

```
<?php 
        wp_nav_menu(array(
        'theme-location'=>'header_menu',
        'menu_class' => 'nav',
        'fallback_cb' => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
        'walker' => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),                     
   )); 
?>
```